# selenium , how to print elements of this html in order as they are?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

if this is the html of a whatsapp message (" how  are you ") then how to iterate through elements of this message and get them (print them) in order as they are by selenium?

```
   <span dir="ltr" class="i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
    <span>
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt=""
            draggable="false" class="b75 emoji wa i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="background-position: -60px -40px;">
        " how "
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt=""
            draggable="false" class="b60 emoji wa i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="background-position: -60px -40px;">
        " are you"
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt=""
            draggable="false" class="b25 emoji wa i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="background-position: -40px -40px;">
    </span>
</span>
```

output this should be

```
 how

 are you
```

or output can also be like this

```
 how  are you
```

i tried this

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("message-in")
for i in range(0,len(chats)):
    messages = chats[i].find_elements_by_class_name("i0jNr")
    for j in range(0,len(messages)):
        if messages[j].text == "" :        
            emojis = chats[i].find_elements_by_class_name("emoji")
            for emoji in emojis:
                print(emoji.get_attribute('alt'))
                break
        else:
            print(messages[j].text)
```

this is giving output as

```
 how
 are you
```

so how to get elements of this in order as they are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the child of `span` element and print the text in case of string and alt text in case of `img` tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag

soup = bs4(html, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'i0jNr'})
s = s.find('span')
for i in s.children:
    if isinstance(i, NavigableString):
        print(i.strip())
    elif isinstance(i, Tag):
        print(i.attrs['alt'])
```

here is code sample for your use case
It's output is for [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qCpz.png) is

```
how

are you
```

Comment: actually i dont know bs4 much ,how to combine selenium and bs4 ?  .this is  whole code    `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions `

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(r'https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input("enter any key :")
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='side']//div//div//label//div//div[@contenteditable='true']")))
searchbox.send_keys('diksha') # enter your sender's name
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
input("enter any key :")`

Comment: `soup = bs4(html, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'i0jNr'})
s = s.find('span')
for i in s.children:
    if isinstance(i, NavigableString):
        print(i.strip())
    elif isinstance(i, Tag):
        print(i.attrs['alt'])`

Comment: this is the whole code @Gr8ayu but its giving error at this place ,actually i dont know bs4  its giving error at html word   `soup = bs4(html, 'html.parser')` what to do for that html word? error is html is not defined @Gr8ayu

Comment: you need to initialize `html` with your html code, you can use like
`html = driver.page_source`